# sqlite : commit to a previous point in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table in which I am inserting songs after syncing the device.

So I have a situation like this

```
.
.
2000 entries
commit 1
.
.
5000 entries
commit 2
.
.
(condition)
```

After syncing the device I have a condition.Based on `(condition)` I want to do either `commit 1` which inserts 2000 entries or `commit 2` which inserts all 5000 entries(including commit 1). Is it possible in sqlite?

On searching I found about savepoints. Is this what I need? or should I use nested `begin - commit` transactions?

PS : I am a newbie to sqlite.

**EDIT**

A very important thing which I forgot to mention is that when I go for `commit 1`, then I do not want to lose next 3000 entries. Because at some point at the end, I have to make `commit 2` also, to have all 5000 entries in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

> Transactions created using BEGIN...COMMIT do not nest. For nested transactions, use the [SAVEPOINT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) and RELEASE commands.

You could use a savepoint like this:

```
BEGIN;
insert 2000 entries
SAVEPOINT step1;
insert 5000 entries
if (...)
    ROLLBACK TO step1;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `SAVEPOINT`s are indeed what you're looking for, try this example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (v);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1);
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t;
SAVEPOINT foo;
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2);
SAVEPOINT bar;
INSERT INTO t VALUES(3);
SELECT * FROM t; -- three rows: 1,2,3
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TO bar;
SELECT * FROM t;  -- the '3' row has gone
RELEASE foo;
SELECT * FROM t; -- still 1 & 2 rows, committed now
```

So your code could go something like

```
SAVEPOINT chunk1;
{2000 entries}
SAVEPOINT chunk2;
{5000 entries}
```

and then either

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TO chunk2;
```

or

```
RELEASE chunk1;
```

depending on your condition.

Comment: Please see the EDIT. So `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TO chunk2;` might (or will actually) loose the next 3000 entries.

Comment: Um. I don't think you should be inserting the first 2000 entries again: you'll get duplicates and I can't think of a way that savepoints could, er, save you. Seems that the first 2000 should always be inserted, the next 3000 optionally?

Comment: Actual case is I have 5000 entries, I want to commit only 2000 entries first and then after some time I want to commit remaining 3000 entries.